# Running a Powershell script on multiple PCs

Tags: powershell, active-directory, outlook

I have modified a script to standardise our organisations signatures in Outlook. The script uses a Word document as a template for the signature and extracts user details from the Active Directory info on our SBS 2003 server.

I am logged in as a Domain Admin and the script works ok for my Outlook signature (there are a couple of errors but it creates the 3x outlook signature files that I need). I can't get it to run on any other computer (but this is the only one with Powershell installed) nor will it run for any other user on this computer.

I would really like to be able to run the script from each workstation. This would be easy if it was a batch file, but it won't work as a powershell script. Do I need to install Powershell on every workstation or is there a simpler way to get it to work?

Also,
I wonder if there is a problem with the script that is not allowing other users to run it from this computer (even with Powershell installed).

Cheers,
Greg

Comment: How do I show the code that my question relates to?

Comment: Greg, check this out for adding code snippets. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22988/how-do-i-add-code-when-replying-to-questions-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need Powershell installed on every machine where you want the script to run. It's included with OS on everything from Server 2008 and Windows 7, but otherwise you'll need to install Powershell manually.

You will also have to enable remote scripting on each machine, since this is disabled by default (for security reasons). Take a look at the following help pages for information and instructions on how to set up:

```
Get-Help about_remote
Get-Help about_remote_FAQ
Get-Help about_remote_requirements
Get-Help about_remote_troubleshooting
```

Comment: Server 2008 R2, not the first version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PowerShell remotely you will need to install it. If you don't want to do that you could look at psexec - that's one of Sys Internals great tools. It will enable you to run commands\scripts remotely.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different suggestion.  Could you generate these signature files for your employees on your machine and then push the signatures out to all the other machines?